# Problem with reading microdata from IPUMS into R

Tags: r

I am trying to read the micro data from the extract that I downloaded from IPUMS USA into R. It seemed simple at first, but I can't get it. I already downloaded the DDI and CSV, and it is not working!

Would appreciate any help as how to how to get this data into R.

I've tried two different ways. I learned how to do this code from this website: https://tech.popdata.org/Integrating-IPUMS-Data-with-R/ (but apparently it was wrong).

Here's my code:

```
cps_ddi <- read_ipums_ddi(ipums_example("wagesdata.xml"))
cps_data <- read_ipums_micro(cps_ddi, data_file = ipums_example("usa_00004.csv"), verbose = FALSE)
```

Console returns this:

> Error in ipums_example("wagesdata.xml") :
>   Could not find file 'wagesdata.xml' in examples. Available files are: cps_00006.csv.gz, cps_00006.dat.gz, cps_00006.xml, cps_00010.dat.gz, cps_00010.xml, cps_00015.dat.gz, cps_00015.xml, nhgis0008_csv.zip, nhgis0008_shape_small.zip`
>
> cps_data <- read_ipums_micro(cps_ddi, data_file = ipums_example("usa_00004.csv"), verbose = FALSE)
>   Error in read_ipums_micro(cps_ddi, data_file = ipums_example("usa_00004.csv"),  : object 'cps_ddi' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ipums_example()` function is designed to find the example data included with the R package.

However, if you're working with your own data, you don't need it.

I believe this should work:

```r
cps_ddi <- read_ipums_ddi("wagesdata.xml")
cps_data <- read_ipums_micro(cps_ddi, data_file = "usa_00004.csv", verbose = FALSE)
```

If it doesn't, then most likely you haven't downloaded the data to your current working directory. You can check where your session is by running command `getwd()` and see what files are currently available with `list.files()`